# spring security login always get access denied

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to learn spring security, so I've downloaded some sample project and then I tried to implement that solution to my project.But when I try to submit login form, I always get 403 page which is defined in applicationContext-security.xml. But I expected is 'authentication-failure-url' for invalid username/pwd, or 'default-target-url' for correct username/pwd rather than 'access-denied-handler' /forbidden(my 403 page).  I'd be really thankful, if somebody, who is more experienced, could help me.
application-Security.xml

```xml
<security:http security="none" pattern="/public/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/login*"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/maxSessionError*"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/forbidden*"/>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         default-target-url="/home"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
    />
    <security:logout  invalidate-session="true"  delete-cookies="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/forbidden"/>
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" >
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"  expired-url="/maxSessionError" />
    </security:session-management>

    <security:custom-filter ref="xunxiSecurityInterceptor" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
</security:http>
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/j_spring_security_check" method="post" class="login-form"  id="login-form" >
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="j_username"/>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="j_password"/>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" /> Remember me </label>
        <button type="submit" >
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: sping 4.2.2 spring-security 4.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write your Spring Security version is 4.0.2 but your JSP seems to be written for Spring Security 3. [Migrate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) your JSP:

- Change login processing URL (form action) to `/login`.
- Change input names to `username` and `password`.
- Add input element for CSRF protection: `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`. CSRF protection is enabled by default from Spring Security 4.

Comment: Yes, it works. I will go through the Spring Security 4.0.2 document reference. Thanks